# JQuery image error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site, I have a JQuery autocomplete. The autocomplete functionality is working fine. I have the data from the query pulling and storing the way I want it to.

This can all be seen [here](http://www.odyssey-gaming.net/combatrating). (Source code can be viewed, Enjin makes it ugly but it's there.)

Currently, the return list is formatted to show a picture if one exists, and a placeholder if one does not.

```
return $("<li>").append("<a>" +
        '<img class="imgThumb" onError="this.src=\'http://files.enjin.com/450575/file_storage/scripts/crScripts/images/placeholder.jpg\';" src="http://census.daybreakgames.com/files/dcuo/images/character/paperdoll/' + item.desc.character_id + '" style="float:left; margin-right: 6px; max-height: 50px;width: auto;">' + '<span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; height:50px;">' + item.value + "<br>CR: " + item.desc.combat_rating + " " + item.desc.world.name + '</span>' + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
    }
```

The blank spot in the center of the page is an area I'd like to make the image from the return list bigger. However, I seem to have hit a snag here. The HTML for this spot on load is:

```
<img id="crCharImage" src="" class="ui-state-default" alt="" />
```

As part of the select function in the autocomplete's JQuery code I have:

```
$("#crCharImage").error(function() {$("#crCharImage").attr( "src", "http://files.enjin.com/450575/file_storage/scripts/crScripts/images/placeholder_large.png");}).attr("src", "http://census.daybreakgames.com/files/dcuo/images/character/paperdoll/" + ui.item.desc.character_id);
```

On characters where the image exists, the code works perfectly. The image displays, all is right in the world. (Can be seen by typing in trex to the Find Characters: input.) On characters where there is no image, instead of going through the onerror function, it just displays a broken image instead of my placeholder (as seen by typing in farm to the input box. Note the logo displayed in the dropdown...which is a smaller version of the placeholder.)

Am I using the .error incorrectly? Or is there another way to override this issue?

**EDIT:** Based on the responses, I went back through and looked at the append function as well as jQuery's built-in functions. I found .html and was able to utilize it to do what I wanted it to. I don't know why I couldn't get that to work initially but thank you to those suggesting looking at it again.

Comment: You're using jQuery and you think it's a good idea to inline an event handler on a generated element? consider: `$('<img>').on(..your code here..).appendTo(yourLink)`

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use the escape character in the onError handle function, just remove the '\' in the onError handle function, change the fisrt code block like this:

```
return $("<li>").append("<a>" +
    '<img class="imgThumb" onerror="this.src='http://files.enjin.com/450575/file_storage/scripts/crScripts/images/placeholder.jpg';" src="http://census.daybreakgames.com/files/dcuo/images/character/paperdoll/' + item.desc.character_id + '" style="float:left; margin-right: 6px; max-height: 50px;width: auto;">' + '<span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; height:50px;">' + item.value + "<br>CR: " + item.desc.combat_rating + " " + item.desc.world.name + '</span>' + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
}
```

Hope this can help

by the way, although the 'onError' works, but I think the correct keyword is 'onerror' for the error callback^_^

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The first code block, the one you quoted, works fine. There's no error in the dropdown return. The issue is in trying to get the final codeblock in the question to work.

Comment: the final code block works fine in my Edge and Chrome with jquery 1.12.1. Since the 'onerror' event in the first code block works fine, why don't you just use this way?